# Create Item using REST API and Branch as template

Tags: sitecore-services-client, branch

I'm trying to use [The RESTful API for the ItemService](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice) to create items based off a branch template. When I pass the branch ID as the TemplateID in the request, the service returns a **400 "Template is invalid"** error.

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a new item based off a branch using the REST API?

Comment: Unless a bug has surfaced in the REST API, this should work out of the box. Please expand your question with the actual URL you are calling and any additional error information you are getting.

Comment: I am also getting the same error when i pass in branch if in template id field.I am using 8.2. Any thoughts