# Create item with branch as template using ItemService API

Tags: sitecore-api, item-web-api, api, itemservice

Good afternoon, I'm trying to create Item using REST API and branch ID as the Template ID the service returns a `400` "`Template is invalid`" error. Does anyone know if there is a way to create a new item based off a branch using the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

For curiosity I had tried this on `10.0.1` instance and can confirm this does not work. While looking at source code responsible for creating Items through REST API/Item Service it seems to specifically call for `database.GetTemplate(templateId)` and there seems to be no fallback for getting branch item which more likely look similar to this code `database.GetItem(branchItem)`.
I would expect this functionality to work with branches and I would advise to open ticket with Sitecore support. Similar question has been asked quite some time ago and would be usuful to get definitive answer for this issue from Sitecore [Create Item using REST API and Branch as template](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/create-item-using-rest-api-and-branch-as-template)