# REST client API, item creation using branch template

Tags: sitecore-api, branch, api

it's the same issue mentioned in: [Create Item using REST API and Branch as template](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/create-item-using-rest-api-and-branch-as-template).

Wanted to know if any solution was found for the issue mentioned in the above post.

I am using version `Sitecore 10.3` and API response returns the same issue `Template is invalid/Bad request`. API Response error attached.

[image]

p.s. : Couldn't add a comment previous post, so posted a new question. I can add more details

Comment: Can you share the code snippet you are using?

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible with Restful Api for ItemService.

The only method that allows create items there is `Create Item` (read https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html for more information). And that method accepts template ID.

When it processes request, it only checks for template with that ID using

```
database.GetTemplate(new ID(request.Template))
```

code and this code does not allow template branches.

I guess you can create a Sitecore Support ticket asking them to extend the functionality, but that will be a feature request.